# Matching single space with newline inside 'if' in AWK

Tags: bash, awk, character, special-characters, newline

I am using awk to extract and evaluate data from text file. I want to match a string having two characters i.e single space character and a newline inside 'if' and perform some operation if checked string contains single space and a newline.

EDIT :: I carefully looked at data and found that strings which I want to match contain single space and a newline character thats why code was failing.
I print that string variable only and redirected to a file.

Binary data of the file ::
`xxd -b stringvalue.txt`  returns

```
00000000: 00100000 00001101
```

This doestn't work ::

```
if ( data[i] == '\s\n')
      action
```

Comment: Use index instead of `==`, i.e `if (index(data[i]," ")`

Comment: `if [[ data[i] == *" "* ]]`

Comment: @pikand That isn't awk...

Comment: [edit] your question to show us a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output and what you have tried so far so we can help you. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Pick the comment of @123 as solution. Now to the why: unless data[i] contains exactly 1 space, your 1st and 2nd if's won't match. The third one won't match anyway, because "\s" is - in your example - interpreted as a string, not a regex.

So, you need either an index to a space or a regex-check.

Take this script:

```
$ cat tst.awk
$0~" " { print "'" $0 "' matches \" \""}
/\s/{ print "'" $0 "' matches /\\s/" }
index($0, " "){ print "'" $0 "' matches index(\$0, \" \")" }
{ if ($0 == " ") print "'" $0 "' exactly matches space" }
```

and test it with:

```
$ echo ' ' | awk -f tst.awk
' ' matches " "
' ' matches /\s/
' ' matches index($0, " ")
' ' exactly matches space
```

and:

```
$ echo ' abc ' | awk -f tst.awk
' abc ' matches " "
' abc ' matches /\s/
' abc ' matches index($0, " ")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Test if a string is a single space

To determine if a string is a single space, we use the equality, `==`, test:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{data[1]="a"; if (data[1] == " ") print "Found space"}'
$ awk 'BEGIN{data[1]="a "; if (data[1] == " ") print "Found space"}'
$ awk 'BEGIN{data[1]=" "; if (data[1] == " ") print "Found space"}'
Found space
```

#### Test if a string has at least one space

To find if a string contains a space, use `data[i] ~ / /`.  This checks to see if `data[i]` matches a regex containing a single space.

Example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{data[1]="abc"; if (data[1] ~ / /) print "Found space"}'
$ awk 'BEGIN{data[1]="a c"; if (data[1] ~ / /) print "Found space"}'
Found space
```

#### Test if a string has one and only one space

If `data[i] ~ / /` is true, then the string `data[i]` has at least one space.

If `data[i] ~ / .* /` is true, then the string `data[i]` has at least two spaces.

To find if `data[i]` has one and only one space, we combine these tests: `data[i] ~ / / && !( data[i] ~ / .* / )` where `!` is awk's logical-not.  For example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{data[1]="a c "; if (data[1] ~ / / && !( data[1] ~ / .* / )) print "Found space"}'
$ awk 'BEGIN{data[1]="a cd"; if (data[1] ~ / / && !( data[1] ~ / .* / )) print "Found space"}'
Found space
```

Comment: This code finds space in a string containing spaces in between as well.  My all strings contain atleast one space.  But some strings have just single space. I want to find out those strings having only one character which is single space.

Comment: @jonny789 Give examples of matching/non matching strings in your question.

Comment: @jonny789 _"I want to find out those strings having only one character which is single space."_  I just updated the answer to include that.